# json tables data how to limit length of td?

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I edited this table i downloaded it with data.json file and i make it get data from database by foreach

I'm using Codeigniter 3

and here's the table code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table data-toggle="table" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1" data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true" >Post ID</th>
                        <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Post ID</th>
                        <th data-field="username"  data-sortable="true">Poster Author</th>
                        <th data-field="post" data-sortable="true">Post</th>
                        <th data-field="tid" data-sortable="true">Topic ID</th>
                        <th data-field="pdate" data-sortable="true">Post Date</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($posts as $post) {
                        echo '
                        <tr>
                        <td>'.$post->pid.'</td>
                        <td>'.$post->pid.'</td>
                        <td>'.$post->author_name.'</td>
                        <td>'.$post->post.'</td>
                        <td>'.$post->topic_id.'</td>
                        <td>'.unix_to_human($post->post_date).'</td>
                        </tr>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--/.row-->
```

My problem is i want to limit max length in post td

```
<td>'.$post->post.'</td>
```

It's possible to make it ?

Comment: Try `strlen()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php with a conditional statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load text helper, than use `character_limiter($str[, $n = 500[, $end_char = '&#8230;']])` like:

```
$string = "Here is a nice text string consisting of eleven words.";
$string = character_limiter($string, 20);
// Returns:  Here is a nice text string
```

or in your case:

```
character_limiter($post->post, 100, '&#8230;');// You should set appropriate length
```

[Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/text_helper.html#character_limiter).

Answer (score 0):

add an inline style ( or set a class stlyle and add this class)  in  the ` related

```
  <th style="maxwidth: 100px;"  data-field= .........>
```